# Google analytic site content is showing incorrect url

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

In my google analytics account, when I click on Behaviour/Site Content/ All pages, the results shows my pages with /www.wmydomainname afterwards which when clicked on it all redirects to "No Page Found"

So each page url has repeats /www.mydomainname afterwards

Please could anyone advise me what was set incorrectly, it shows a very high bounce rate and not sure if this is because of the wrong page urls.

Thank you
Fiona

Comment: That's impossible to answer without looking at your setup - it might be a filter (in admin -> view -> Filters) that  adds the domain to the url path or you are passing a wrong path as argument to your tracking code (the "page not found" error happens because Analytics hast stored the wrong path and is irrelevant). This should not affect your bounce rate. Alas there is no way to remove the error from data that is already collected.

Comment: Thanks, I've had someone to look at it and now it's showing correct url's. It was apparently "The problem was in the view settings where 'Default page' was filled in incorrectly. In most cases, it's fine to leave the field blank."